# Escape character for Location of char in a string: R lang

Tags: regex, r, escaping

I'm trying to get the location of `\` or `/` in a string. Below is the code I'm attempting:

```
x <- "<span id=\"ref_12590587_l\">6,803.61</span>_l>"
gregexpr("\\\", x)
which(strsplit(x, "")[[1]]=="\")
```

My problem is when I attempt these codes in Rstudio, I get a continue prompt, the REPL prompt becomes `+`. These codes work for other characters.

Why I'm getting the continue prompt, even though the `\` is quoted in the inverted quotes?

**Edit:** corrected the string after comment.

Comment: You do not have  "\" in your input string. If you want to look for a `/`, just use `gregexpr("/", x)`, and if you want to look for "\", use `gregexpr("\\\\", x)`.

Comment: Edited the string to correct one. @stribizhev  Would you mind explaining the 4 escapes `\\\\` part please?

Comment: `gregexpr` expects a regular expression. In regular expressions, "\" is a special symbol, thus it must be escaped for the regex engine. But in `gregexpr`, we pass a string that itself is using "\" for escaping entities like `\n`. So, we need to escape the backslash for R first, and then for the regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another slash (as stribizhev says in the comments). So you're looking for

`gregexpr("\\\\", x)`

The reason why is that the you need to escape the `\`, twice. So `\\` gives you only 1 backslash. When you put 3 in, the 3rd backslash is actually escaping the quote!

See for an example:

`gregexpr("\"", 'hello, "hello"')`

This is searching for the quote in the string.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there any source for more such nuances like this?

Comment: see [intro to R character vectors](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Character-vectors) for a start...

Answer (score 1):

Just to formalize my comments:

1. Your `x` variable does not contain any backslashes, these are escaping characters that allow us putting literal quotation marks into a string.
2. `gregexpr("\\\", x)` contains a non-closed string literal because the quotation mark on the right is escaped, and thus is treated as a literal quotation mark, not the one that is used to "close" a string literal.
3. To search for a literal `\` in `gregexpr`, we need 4 backslashes `\\\\`, as `gregexpr` expects a regular expression. In regular expressions, "\" is a special symbol, thus it must be escaped for the regex engine. But inside `gregexpr`, we pass a string that itself is using `\` for escaping entities like `\n`. So, we need to escape the backslash for R first, and then for the regex engine.

That said, you can use

```
gregexpr("\\\\", x)
```

to get only literal backslashes, or

```
gregexpr("\\\\|/", x)
```

to also look for forward slashes.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/D7OneJ)